# XLSXデータの形式を変換したい

Tags: python, excel

下記のxlsxファイルからデータを抽出し、
xlsxファイルと同様にB列”個”、C列をパーセント表示にしたいです。
`col.number_format = "0.0%"`の形式で指定しましたが、結果の通りに何も変換されないです。

xlsxのデータ

```
 A       B     C         
アメリカ  1234個  66.7%　 
カナダ　 1234個　4.9%
```

code

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx',data_only=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]


for row in ws["A1:C2"]:
    values = []
    for col in row:
        values.append(col.value)
        col.number_format = openpyxl.styles.numbers.FORMAT_NUMBER
        col.number_format = "0.0%"
    print(values)
```

結果

```
[' ', 'A', 'B', 'C']
['アメリカ', 1234, 0.6666666666666666]
['カナダ', 1234, 0.04938271604938271]
```

理想の結果

```
['A',    'B', 'C']
['アメリカ', 1234個, 66.7%]
['カナダ', 1234個, 4.9%]
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: それはEXCELファイルの中身としてのフォーマット指定であって、変更された結果をEXCELで見たり印刷したりする場合の指定でしょう。Pythonに取り込んだデータをPythonでPrint()表示する際の指定では無いのでは？ Pythonのスクリプトからの表示の際に形式を変えたいのなら、Pythonスクリプトの中でEXCELへの指定と同様の編集を行う必要があるのでは？ それから、提示されたソースでは全部のセルの書式が数値で`%`表示になってしまうのと、変更された結果を`xlsx`ファイルに`save`していないので確認は出来ないと思うのですが。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。EXCELでは既に%として表示されていて保存されていますが上記の結果のように0.66666666として表示されます。

Comment: 既に希望する書式になっているEXCELを、何故Pythonで再度同じ書式に設定するのでしょう？ 何もしなくても良いのでは？

Comment: 何もなく設定すると関数として読み込んでしまい=B1/C1として読み込まれます。C列には関数が入っておりましてそのためdata_only=Trueとして表示します。

Comment: そういう返答を聞くと、[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)のように見えます。貴方が直面している「本当の問題」は何ですか？ それを整理して質問した方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 失礼いたしました。まとめて具体的に記載します。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122750/discussion-between-sakaolo-and-kunif)しましょう。

Comment: ディスカッションの方に入ってます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col.number_format` や `col.style` を変更しても内部の数値表現形式には反映されないので、スクリプト内で計算してしまうと良いかと思います。

```py
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx', data_only=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

for row in ws["A1:C2"]:
  values = []
  for col in row:
    if col.column_letter == 'C':
      col.value = f'{col.value*100:.1f}%'
    values.append(col.value)
  print(values)

=>
['アメリカ', '1234個', '66.7%']
['カナダ', '1234個', '4.9%']
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらで問題なくいけました！！